# Underline on hover Cocoa - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have been trying to underline on hover a NSTextField. I what happened with my first attempt was that the text was underlined, but it went on top of the previous text. With another attempt, it become increasingly bold.

```
-(void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
if (is_underlined)
    return;
is_underlined = YES;

//NSDictionary *attrsDictionary =   [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] forKey:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName];
//NSMutableAttributedString * as =  [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.event.label
                                                         //         attributes:attrsDictionary];
//[as autorelease];
NSMutableAttributedString * as = [[[self attributedStringValue] mutableCopy] autorelease];
[as beginEditing];
[as addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName
           value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle]
           range:[[[self window] fieldEditor:YES forObject:self] selectedRange]];

[as endEditing];
[self setAttributedStringValue:as];
}

-(void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    if (!is_underlined)
        return;
    is_underlined = NO;
   // self.stringValue = self.event.label;
    //[self setAttributedStringValue:nil];
    NSMutableAttributedString * as = [[[self attributedStringValue] mutableCopy] autorelease];
    [as beginEditing];
    [as removeAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName range:[[[self window] fieldEditor:YES forObject:self] selectedRange]];
   // [as addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName
      //         value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]
     //          range:[[[self window] fieldEditor:YES forObject:self] selectedRange]];

    [as endEditing];
    [self setAttributedStringValue:as];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I have found the answer - it lies not in the code itself, but in the code the demo code that I was building off of. The author implemented these views in drawRect which meant that each time the rectangle was drawn, a new textfield was created in the same location.